# How to use didFinishEditing (textField) with custom cells?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have custom cells that each have a textfield in them. When I change the text in them, I'd like to get the current row, and then update my array correctly. So far I don't think I've even been able to make the didFinishEditing run at all. I put a simple print-command there, and when I changed the textFields, nothing was printed out. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to put the function, in the cell's class, or the main class. In the main class it doesn't run, and in the cell-class it can't give me the index path.row.

Here's what I've tried:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ itemTitle: UITextField) {
    let pointInTable = itemTitle.convert(itemTitle.bounds.origin, to: self.tableView)

    let textFieldIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: pointInTable)


    items.insert(itemTitle.text!, at: textFieldIndexPath)

    //tableView.reloadData()(This isn't really that important)
}
```

And also this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ itemTitle: UITextField) {

    items.insert(itemTitle.text!, at: indexPath.row)

    //tableView.reloadData()(This isn't really that important)
```

}

Here's my cell class:

```
class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!


    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        itemTitle.resignFirstResponder()
    }//(Not relevant)
```

}

In my main class I've the following:

```
class PreviewToDoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

And a screenshot of how my view is laid out:

[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCCeS.png)

I just picked up custom cells so I'm beginning to learn. I've used .default and .subtitle cells as well as tableviews before.

Thank you for any answers!

Comment: I think you forget to add textfield.delegate = self

Comment: The did end editing is called once the keyboard "done" is pressed (and the delegate must be set as well). You need to add a target for value change, you can drag it from the interface builder and select action. (or it might be "editing changed")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not getting anything printed out because the UITextFieldDelegate has to be in your TableViewCell, then you can use a delegate to pass the cell and the text that you are using in the textField to the viewController and there you can access your tableView and you indexPath.

Try something like this:

Here you create your delegate and put the textField delegate to your customCell

```
protocol ItemTableViewCellDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(text: String, cell: ItemTableViewCell)
}


class ItemTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var itemTitle: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!

    var delegate: ItemTableViewCellDelegate?

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        itemTitle.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        itemTitle.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            delegate?.textFieldDidEndEditing(text: text, cell: self)
        }
    }
}
```

And them your class extends from you custom delegate. In the delegate function you can access the indexPath with indexPath(for: cell)

```
class PreviewToDoViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ItemTableViewCellDelegate {

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(text: String, cell: ItemTableViewCell) {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell) {
            items.insert(text, at: textFieldIndexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I did to solve this, but it was something along these lines, thank you!

Comment: Hi Toumax if you want a help to understand what happened let me know.